# how to not inherit some or all parent persistence attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

As shown below, i have the object Car with 2 persistence attributes:

```
public  class Car {

@Column(name = "COLOR")
protected String color;

@Column(name = "BRAND")
protected String brand;
}
```

All objects that extends from Car use the 2 attributes, but in some the them, i want to exclude one or all attributes.
For example:

```
public  class SpecialCar extends Car{
    //how to tell here that i don't want to have Brand column

}
```

Thx for help

Comment: Well, I don't know if that's possible coz if anything is `protected`or `public` or has no modifier, then it **will** be inherited. If something is `private` it is **not** inherited.

Comment: You should check out the @AttributeOverride annotation from hibernate. e.g. as used in: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritance-table-per-concrete-class-annotation-xml-mapping/

Comment: Don't do that. If a `SpecialCar` extends a `Car`, then, for all that matters, it must behave as a `Car` (if a `Car` has brands, so it also must have). If you don't do like that, it is a violation to the [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) of OO software, which leads to complicated and hard to understand/maintain software. If you still want to have the `SpecialCar` being different, then I suggest using [composition instead of inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want it in SpecialCar then, to me, it means, it should not be in Car at all. Can't you simply remove it from Car?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is answered allready here:

[Disabling inherited method on derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486402/disabling-inherited-method-on-derived-class)

I also think that is not possible, but they give you a nice trick