# Inheritance functions in java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

Duplicate of [Disabling inherited method on derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486402/disabling-inherited-method-on-derived-class)

This is my class codes:

```
class Parent{
    public bool sum(int a){return true;}

    public int mul(int a){return a*a;}

}
```

and two another classes that extends parent class:

```
class derived extend parent{
    //here this child can see two methods of parent class and
    //I want just see sum method in here and don't see mul method
}
class derivedb extend parent{
//here this child can see two methods of parent class and
//I want here just see mul method.
}
```

Comment: IMHO U can put private for mul function if u r not using this parent in any other place

Comment: i do not understand the question. do u want to hide mul function of do you want the sum function to be in derived class?

Comment: Please note that Java has nothing like 'functions' but only 'Methods'. Somebody please edit the question.

Comment: If you want the `mul` method to be externally visible but prevent any subclass from redefining it, then you're going to need to make the `mul` method `final`.

Comment: Also `bool` is not a specific primitive type of java. Use `boolean` if that's what you mean or make it capital like `Bool` if it's user-specific class

Comment: Damn.. wrong duplicate. It should have been http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486402/disabling-inherited-method-on-derived-class

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by making `mul` as private method in Parent class. So the mul method has visibility only inside `Parent` class

```
class Parent{
    public bool sum(int a){return true;}

    private int mul(int a){return a*a;}

}
```

Comment: This is while I had just one class!